# Discord.net event only calls the first subscriber

Tags: c#, events, discord.net

I have two methods subscribed to the `ReactionAdded` event, but when the event triggers, only the first subscriber called and the others are not. Why doesn't it work and how can it be repaired?

### Code

```
_client.ReactionAdded += HelpPageUpdater.ReactionAdded;
_client.ReactionAdded += GameCore.ReactionAdded;

static class GameCore
{
    public static async Task ReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> msg, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {// <-- Not executed
     //DODE...
    }
}
static class HelpPageUpdater
{
    public static async Task ReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> msg, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {//<-- Executed
     //CODE...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that the first subscriber has an exception (which is not visible in the question), after fixing that issue the problem was solved.